# бот не выводит информацию из бд python telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot

вот кусок кода не могу найти проблему.ПОМОГИТЕ!!!

```
if message.text=="скидки": 
   connect = sqlite3.connect('bdBot.db')
    #вывод из базы данных 
   cursorObj = connect.cursor()
   cursorObj.execute("SELECT * FROM skidka_tabl")
   rows = cursorObj.fetchall()

   messege_str=""
   i=0
   while i<5:
     messege_str += f"rows\n"
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id,messege_str, reply_markup = markup)
```

Comment: Обратите внимание на цикл while, она работает до тех пор, пока i меньше 5. Но в цикле вы не повышаете i. Поэтому получается бесконечный цикл, и скрипт не доходит до отправки сообщения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## решение проблемы

```
  if message.text=="скидки": 
   connect = sqlite3.connect('bdBot.db')
    #вывод из базы данных 
   cursorObj = connect.cursor()
   cursorObj.execute("SELECT * FROM skidka_tabl")
   rows = cursorObj.fetchall()

   message_str=""
   i=0
   
   while i<4:
     message_str +=f"{rows[i]}\n"
     i += 1 

   bot.send_message(message.chat.id,message_str, reply_markup = markup)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вам:

```
 i=0
 while i<5:
```

Это бесполезный кусок кода, тк он ничего не делает, если же вы хотели сделать отправку через время то используйте:

`time.sleep(время в секундах)`

а решение очень простое уберите эту часть кода(указанна выше)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: если я убераю эту часть кода, то также ничего не происходит